# Finding the least upper bound in $\mathbb R$ of the set $\{x \in \mathbb Q \mid x^2<a \}$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to find the least upper bound of the set $A = \{x \in \mathbb Q \mid x^2<a \}$ ($a \gt 0$) in $\mathbb R$ without using the Archimedean property or the density of rationals in $\mathbb R$. I am asking because in the textbook "Fundamentals of Mathematical Analysis" - Paul Sally this exercise is given before the Archimedean property or density of rationals is introduced. 
My unfinished solution of the exercise: 
$ 0 \in A$ and $A$ is bounded: $(a+1)^2 = a^2 +2a +1 > a$, therefore $x^2<a \implies x^2 < (a+1)^2 \implies x<a+1$. Since $A \subset \mathbb R$ it has a least upper bound $\alpha$.
Case 1: $\,$ $\alpha^2 > a$ it can be shown there exists $q \in \mathbb R_{\gt 0}$ such that $\alpha^2 >q^2 > a$. 
Choose $\,$ $\varepsilon = \alpha -q = \frac{\alpha ^2 -a }{2 \alpha}$ , then $q = \alpha - \varepsilon = \frac{\alpha ^2 +a }{2 \alpha}<\alpha$ $\;$ (since $\alpha ^2 > a \implies \alpha > \frac{a}{\alpha} \implies \frac{\alpha}{2} > \frac{a}{2 \alpha} \implies \alpha > \frac{\alpha^2 + a}{2 \alpha}$). 
Also $\alpha^2>q^2$ $\;$ (since $\alpha^2>a \implies 2 \alpha^2>\alpha^2+ a \implies 4 \alpha^4>(\alpha^2+ a)^2 \implies \alpha^2> \left(\frac{\alpha^2+ a}{2\alpha}\right)^2 =q^2$) 
Therefore $\alpha$ can't be more than $a$. 
Case 2: $\alpha^2<a$. By using similar arguments as in the previous case it can be shown that $\alpha$ must be irrational since otherwise there would exist a rational number $q>0$ such that $\alpha^2<q^2<a$, hence $\alpha$ wouldn't be an upper bound (since $q \in A$).
That's as far as I have gotten, and I don't know how to show that $\alpha^2=a$ without using the Archimedean property of $\mathbb R$ and the density of the rationals.